# Manipulating a string on the fly using strpos

Tags: php, hyperlink, strpos

I have a program that generates a link and I want to change how the link appears go get a modification to work. I have not been able to figure out where and how the link in generated. I just thought it would be easier to change the end product to what I needed.

The code generates a  link like this:

```
 report/custom_report.php?printable=1&pdf=0&LBF013_13370=72517&
```

The code that generates the link is this:

```
 a href="custom_report.php?printable=1&<?php print postToGet($ar); ?>
```

I need the link to be this:

```
 report/custom_report.php?printable=1&LBF013_13370=72517&
```

I have tried this:

```
$link = postToGet($ar);
$find = 'pdf=0';
$Nlink = strpos($link, $find); 
print $link;
```

But it returns just the 0 only.
If I print to the screen $link I get

```
pdf=0&LBF013_13370=72517&
```

Should I be using a different command to change this string? I thought that if I loaded it into a variable the strpo would work to remove the pdf=0 and leave the rest. Then my code mod would work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the examples in the `strpos` man page of PHP online documentation to see what is wrong with your current code. Then you can have a look at `preg_replace` or `str_replace` and Bob will be your uncle in no time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [str_replace](https://www.php.net/str_replace) rather than str_pos:

```
$finalLink = str_replace('pdf=0','',$link)
```